# Istio Ingress not showing address (Kubeflow on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks, istio, kubeflow

I'm trying to setup kubeflow on AWS, I did follow [this](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/aws/deploy/install-kubeflow/) tutorial to setup kubeflow on AWS.

I used dex instead of cognito with [following policy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/manifests/v1.2-branch/kfdef/kfctl_aws.v1.2.0.yaml).

then at step: `kfctl apply -V -f kfctl_aws.yaml` , first I received this error:

```text
IAM for Service Account is not supported on non-EKS cluster
```

So to fix this I set the property `enablePodIamPolicy: false`

Then retried and it successfully deployed kubeflow, on checking services status using `kubectl -n kubeflow get all`, I found all services ready except MPI operator.

ignoring this when I tried to run `kubectl get ingress -n istio-system`
I got the following result.

[image]

upon investigation using `kubectl -n kubeflow logs $(kubectl get pods -n kubeflow --selector=app=aws-alb-ingress-controller --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})`

I found the following error:

```text
E1104 12:09:37.446342       1 controller.go:217] kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to reconcile LB managed SecurityGroup: failed to reconcile managed LoadBalancer securityGroup: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: Lsvzm7f4rthL4Wxn6O8wiQL1iYXQUES_9Az_231BV7fyjgs7CHrwgUOVTNTf4334_C4voUogjSuCoF8GTOKhc5A7zAFzvcGUKT_FBs6if06KMQCLiCoujgfoqKJbG75pPsHHDFARIAdxNYZeIr4klmaUaxbQiFFxpvQsfT4ZkLMD7jmuQQcrEIw_U0MlpCQGkcvC69NRVVKjynIifxPBySubw_O81zifDp0Dk8ciRysaN1SbF85i8V3LoUkrtwROhUI9aQYJgYgSJ1CzWpfNLplbbr0X7YIrTDKb9sMhmlVicj_Yng0qFka_OVmBjHTnpojbKUSN96uBjGYZqC2VQXM1svLAHDTU1yRruFt5myqjhJ0fVh8Imhsk1Iqh0ytoO6eFoiLTWK4_Crb8XPS5tptBBzpEtgwgyk4QwOmzySUwkvNdDB-EIsTJcg5RQJl8ds4STNwqYV7XXeWxYQsmL1vGPVFY2lh_MX6q1jA9n8smxITE7F6AXsuRHTMP5q0jk58lbrUe-ZvuaD1b0kUTvpO3JtwWwxRd7jTKF7xde2InNOXwXxYCxHOw0sMX56Y1wLkvEDTLrNLZWOACS-T5o7mXDip43U0sSoUtMccu7lpfQzH3c7lNdr9s2Wgz4OqYaQYWsxNxRlRBdR11TRMweZt4Ta6K-7si5Z-rrcGmjG44NodT0O14Gzj-S4i6bK-qPYvUEsVeUl51ev_MsnBKtCXcMF8W6j9D7Oe3iGj13uvlVJEtq3OIoRjBXIuQQ012H0b3nQqlkoKEvsPAA_txAjgHXVzEVcM301_NDQikujTHdnxHNdzMcCfY7DQeeOE_2FT_hxYGlbuIg5vonRTT7MfSP8_LUuoIICGS81O-hDXvCLoomltb1fqCBBU2jpjIvNALMwNdJmMnwQOcIMI_QonRKoe5W43v\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: a9be63bd-2a3a-4a21-bb87-93532923ffd2"  "controller"="alb-ingress-controller" "request"={"Namespace":"istio-system","Name":"istio-ingress"}
```

I don't understand what exactly went wrong in security permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

The `alb-ingress-controller` doesn't have permission to create an ALB.

By setting the `enablePodIamPolicy: false`, I assume you go for option 2 of the guide.

The `alb-ingress-controller` uses the `kf-admin` role, and the installer needs attach on that role a policy found in `aws-config/iam-alb-ingress-policy.json`. Most probably it's not installed, so you'll have to add it in IAM and attach it to the role.

After doing that, observe the reconciler logs of the `alb-ingress-controller` to see if it's able to create the ALB.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the `cluster-name` in the `aws-alb-ingress-controller-config` is not correctly configured.

If that's the case, you should edit the Config Map to the right cluster name using `kubectl edit cm aws-alb-ingress-controller-config -n kubeflow`.

After that you should delete the pod so it restarts (`kubectl -n kubeflow delete pod $(kubectl get pods -n kubeflow --selector=app=aws-alb-ingress-controller --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})`).